# VBScript Search Excel Workbook for Value from another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I am new to VB scripting, so please, bear with me!  I am trying to create a script that uses worksheets from two different excel workbooks.  It opens the first worksheet and iterates through a specified range.  I want it to then take the value of each cell in that range and search the second worksheet (in a different workbook) and search for the value that was found in the first worksheet, and if the value is found, return the address of the cell it was found in.  For example:

```
Worksheet1
╔══════╦═════╗
║ Name ║ Age ║
╠══════╬═════╣
║ Matt ║  22 ║
║ Jeff ║  13 ║
╚══════╩═════╝

Worksheet2
╔═══════╦════════════╗
║ Name  ║    DOB     ║
╠═══════╬════════════╣
║ Dave  ║ 09/12/2001 ║
║ Frank ║ 01/25/1992 ║
║ Jeff  ║ 10/10/2013 ║
╚═══════╩════════════╝
```

So the script would output: `A4`
Because it found one of the values from the specified range (`A2:A3`) of the first worksheet in the second worksheet and is returning the location of that cell.

Here is the code I have:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Dim val

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\username\file.xlsx")
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\username\file2.xlsx")
Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1")


For Each c In objworksheet.Range("A2:A3").Cells
    val = c.value
    Set objRange = objWorksheet2.UsedRange
    Set found = objRange.Find(val)
    Wscript.Echo found.AddressLocal(False,False)
Next
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

> Error: Object required: 'found'

I am sure there is something obvious I am missing here but I have been spinning my wheels for quite some time and was hoping someone could provide some feedback.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for the formatting edits @Bond !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Find()` function returns a `Range` object if successful or `Nothing` if not. So you need to test the return value to ensure it's a `Range` object before you try accessing its properties and methods.

```
For Each c In objworksheet.Range("A2:A3").Cells
    val = c.value
    Set objRange = objWorksheet2.UsedRange
    Set found = objRange.Find(val)

    ' Test for success!
    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        Wscript.Echo found.AddressLocal(False,False)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Ahhh, that makes a great deal of sense!  Thank you!

When I do this, it does not find the value in the second excel sheet, even though when I hardcode the value to find, it finds it no problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: I would set a breakpoint on your `Find()` statement and ensure that `val` is what you expect it to be. The default parameters for `Find()` will search for a partial match (`LookAt:=xlPart` vs `xlWhole`) and also search without regard to case (`MatchCase:=False`) so it's pretty "open" by default. The names in Worksheet2 are typed in directly, correct? They're not formula-driven?

Comment: Thank you - ended up having an exra white space in Worksheet 1 and that is why it wasn't able to find it in worksheet 2.  Thank you again for all of your help!